# How can we prove that a set $A$ of subsets of $X$ is an algebra of $X$?

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

If $X$ is a finite set, and $A$ is a set of subsets of $X$, is $A$ an algebra set of $X$?

For example: If $X$ contains $5$ elements, can an algebra $A$ of $X$ have only $31$ subsets of $X$?

I tried to prove that it's wrong by contradiction, that is, not every subset of $X$ belongs to $A$ have a complement in $A$.

Comment: Hi! welcome to MSE. Where did your proof failed? could you give more details on your work?

Comment: I assmed that *A* have 31 subsets of X and *A* is an Algebra. So Φ belongs to *A*,, and each subset of X that belongs to *A* also have a complement that belongs to *A*
And the finite union of elements of *A* belongs to *A* 
Since Φ belongs to *A* then X also belongs to *A*
So we have 29 subsets of X should belong to *A*
Since any set have a unique complement.. then one of the subsets that belongs to *A* doesn't have complement that belongs to *A*

I hope I explained it right

Comment: I'm not even sure that the statement is True.. So I'm just wondering if it's True or not..and why? 
And if not was my explanation right? 


But I'm just thinking that an Algebra can only have even number of subsets of X ( an Algebra have even number of elements )

Comment: Where is that $31$ (and $29$) coming from?

Comment: The number of elements in the algebra (its elements are subsets of X)

Comment: You seem to simply miss one of the subsets, in that case.

Answer (score 0):

The power set $P(X)$ contains exactly $2^{|X|}$ elements: subsets of $X$ correspond to functions $X\to\{0,1\}$ (assign $1$ to exactly those elements that are in the given subset, and for the other direction, take the preimage of $\{1\}$).

So, here if $A=P(X)$, then it is certainly a set algebra, and indeed $|A|=32$ is even.

You are right that any finite nontrivial set algebra must have an even number of elements, since no subset can be its own complement.

Moreover, any finite set algebra has cardinality $2^k$, because they naturally carry a *vector space* structure over the two element field $\Bbb Z/2\Bbb Z$, with the symmetric difference as addition.

Comment: I found your argument very interesting, I see how the finite set algebra carries a vector space structure over $\mathbb{Z} / 2 \mathbb{Z}$ with the addition you mentioned. How does this vector space structure ensures a cardinality of $2^k$? is it just because for any element $x$ we must have its symmetric $-x$?

Comment: No, it's because of the existence of a *basis* and the uniqueness of coordinates, thus, all $n$ dimensional vector spaces over any field $F$ are isomorphic to $F^n$.